# Instagram Integration display hashtag content

Tags: api, instagram, hashtag

I want to display hashtag content and public content on my website. However, Instagram said--

> This use case is not supported. We do not approve the public_content permission for one-off projects such as displaying hashtag based content on your website. As alternative solution, you can show your own Instagram content, or find a company that offers this type of service (content discover, moderation, and display).

Are there any other ways display the images via hashtag? I tried contacting instagram support but there is no reply. I read that instagram support never replies, so that's unfortunate. Are there anybody here that tried and successfully get hashtag content from different users and display it on their website?

Comment: Yeah, not possible now from Instagram api.

Comment: Instagram stopped taking new application review submissions for public_content scope permission. Finding third party providers who already have got the permission could be one solution. But, the problem is they are very costly. I found https://www.socialmediawall.io that looks the best at the moment.